# Unable to upgrade Win10 tech preview on VMWare player

Tags: vmware-player, windows-10-preview

I have had Win10 tech preview running perfectly well on a VMWare Player virtual machine with 60GB HD, 2 processors and 2GB of RAM.  Now I get a prompt "Install a new build of Windows now".  I am warned that my PC will restart every few hours.  When I click on "More info" I'm directed to the MS website to a download link for the file "Windows10TechnicalPreview.exe".  When I run this I get the error message "We ran into an installation error.  This might be because your PC doesn't meet system requirement or your language isn't available".  No further information is given.

My VMWare player is the latest version.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Any reason not to just wipe your test VM and install a new one with the latest **preview** ?

Comment: What build do you have right now and what build do you want to install.

Comment: which Win10 Build do you run?

Comment: I'm running 9841.  Hotfix didn't install.  Will reinstall new preview.

Comment: yes, 9841 expired on 15th April. So, yes, install build 10041 via ISO and update to 10061.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by downloading the latest .iso and running setup.exe from within Win10 tech preview.  This successfully upgraded my system.

Answer (score -1):

Probably caused by your install of Windows 10 Technical Preview version expiring.

Hotfix to extend until May 2015: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46447.

Comment: That hotfix only applies to Windows Server, but based on [this](http://www.neowin.net/news/some-windows-10-builds-will-stop-booting-after-april-30th) information by Microsoft, clearly indicates there there is still a hard cutoff date that **cannot** be extended.  A hotfix that does not apply to Windows 10 Technical Preview isn't helpful.